# ADO Connection String to query a CSV File - "Not a Valid Path.." Error

Tags: vba, csv, connection-string, ado

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my Connection String. I'm looking to query an Excel.CSV file.

```
Sub test()

Dim myConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim recSet As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim myPath As String
Dim connStrng As String
Dim qryStrng As String
Dim ReiterName As String

myPath = "C:\Users\FirstName.LastName\Desktop\temp.csv"

connStrng = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & myPath & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

Debug.Print connStrng

myConn.Open connStrng <-- 'C:\Users\FirstName.LastName\Desktop\temp.csv' Not a valid path error
```

Comment: Since it's a CSV file, do not include full path in the path, try only "C:\Users\FirstName.LastName\Desktop\"

Comment: @Bharat How/where do i specify what file i want to query?

Comment: Filename is the table specified in the SELECT, for example "SELECT * FROM temp.csv;"

Comment: BTW you should consider using ACE instead of JET (better support for 64 bits environments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full code for reference

```
Sub test()

    Dim myConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim recSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim connStrng As String
    Dim qryStrng As String
    Dim ReiterName As String

    myPath = "C:\Users\FirstName.LastName\Desktop\"

    connStrng = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
              "Data Source=" & myPath & ";" & _
              "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

    Debug.Print connStrng

    myConn.Open connStrng

    recSet .Open "SELECT * FROM temp.csv", myConn
    runSQLQueryForCSV = RecSet.GetRows()

    myConn.Close
    Set recSet = Nothing
    Set myConn = Nothing
End Function
```